# obtain absolute position of a view inside a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiview

I have a table view cell with images and labels. I want to add an animation that an image duplicate of a selected cell fly to a point outside the tableview.

I have passed the tableview cell pointer out of the tableview controller.  And when I do the duplication, I found the frame of the original image can not be used ouside its superview, i.e. the cell. How could I convert the frame to the [0,0,1024,768] coordiation system? Thanks!

```
animateImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:cell.thumbnail.image];
[animateImageView setFrame:cell.thumbnail.frame];

[self.view addSubview:animateImageView];
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^(void) {
                     [UIView setAnimationTransition:103 forView:animateImageView cache:YES];
                     [UIView setAnimationPosition: CGPointMake(262, 723)];

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     [animateImageView removeFromSuperview];

                 }
 ];
[animateImageView release];
```

Answer (score 3):

The `convertPoint:toView:` method on the `UIView` object should give you what you need.

```
- (CGPoint)convertPoint:(CGPoint)point toView:(UIView *)view
```

> **view**
>
> The view with point in its coordinate system. If view is nil, this
>   method instead converts from window base coordinates. Otherwise, both
>   view and the receiver must belong to the same UIWindow object.

[Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-BBCCDCGF)

You could do something along the lines of:

```
CGPoint point = [self.view convertPoint:self.view.frame.origin toView:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks! But it seems I should be using convertPoint: fromView: ? since this code is run outside the tableview controller. However, I tried animateImageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:cell.thumbnail.image] autorelease];
    CGPoint origin = cell.thumbnail.frame.origin;
    [self.view convertPoint:origin fromView:cell.thumbnail]; But I am still not getting the correct origin. Debugging showed the origin is (0,0), which is in the cell cooridination.